# Radio button highlighting

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, radio-button, highlight, coldfusion-10

Here is my current code:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="nosupp" name="nosupp">
    No Supplier Chosen
</label><br/><br/>

<cfloop query="supplier">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="chk1" name="chooseSupp" onchange="change(this);">
      Chosen Supplier
  </label>
</cfloop>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function change(obj) {
    var tr=obj.parentNode.parentNode;
    var tbl = tr.parentNode.parentNode;
    var inputs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++)
      inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
      tr.style.backgroundColor=(obj.checked)? 'red' : 'transparent';
  }
</script>
```

What this does is, highlights each of the radio buttons in the loop whenever they are clicked on.

My problem is, when I click on the radio button outside the loop (nosupp), the highlighting on the last one checked in the loop does not go away.

I don't want any highlighting on the nosupp one or when the nosupp one is chosen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this (I assume that your nosupp and supp are in the same parent table or else modify this code according to your need):

```
<input type="radio" id="nosupp" name="nosupp" onchange="resetSupp(this);">

<script type="text/javascript">
function resetSupp(obj) {
var tr=obj.parentNode.parentNode;
var tbl = tr.parentNode.parentNode;
var inputs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++)
  inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
  tr.style.backgroundColor= 'transparent';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're selecting based on type "input" when you need to only select some.  All I've done is add `class="chooseSupp"` to the inputs inside the loop and changed your selector in your javascript to `var inputs = tbl.getElementsByClassName("chooseSupp");`.  Give it a try and let me know how it goes.

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="nosupp" name="nosupp">
    No Supplier Chosen
</label><br/><br/>

<cfloop query="supplier">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="chk1" name="chooseSupp" class="chooseSupp" onchange="change(this);">
      Chosen Supplier
  </label>
</cfloop>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function change(obj) {
    var tr=obj.parentNode.parentNode;
    var tbl = tr.parentNode.parentNode;
    var inputs = tbl.getElementsByClassName("chooseSupp");
    for(var i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++)
      inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
      tr.style.backgroundColor=(obj.checked)? 'red' : 'transparent';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this didn't stop the radio buttons in the loop from being highlighted.

Comment: Did you add the class to every input or just the ones inside the loop?  The command `getElementsByClassName` should only select the elements with that class.

Comment: Just the ones in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the same name for each input that's part of the group, so change:

```
<input type="radio" id="nosupp" name="nosupp">
```

to

```
<input type="radio" id="nosupp" name="chooseSupp">
```

Answer (score 0):

> give id for all input elements as panel

```
    .setTransparent{background:transparent}

    if($(input[name==chooseSupp] :checked))
    $("#panel :input").addClass(setTransparent);

   // write other conditions
    $("#panel :input").removeClass(setTransparent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div_myradgroup">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" id="nosupp" name="chooseSupp" onchange="change(this, true);">No Supplier Chosen
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="chk1" name="chooseSupp" onchange="change(this);">Chosen Supplier
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="chk2" name="chooseSupp" onchange="change(this);">Chosen Supplier
    </label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var group = document.getElementById('div_myradgroup');
    if (!group) {
        // you decide what should happen if you're expecting it to be in the dom
    }

    function change(obj, nohlight) {
        var label = obj.parentNode,
            inputs = group.getElementsByTagName("input"),
            inp = null; // a single input assigned to in loop

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inp = inputs[i];
            if (inp.getAttribute('type') === 'radio') {
                inp.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
            }
        }

        if (!nohlight) {
            label.style.backgroundColor = (obj.checked) ? 'red' : 'transparent';
        }
    }

</script>
```